# How to find indices of the largest N elements in a cell?

Tags: matlab, cells

I Matlab, I know that I can use this to get the largest number of a cell.

```
cell_max = cellfun(@(x) max(x(:)), the_cell);
```

However, there are two problems with this. First, I need the index of the maximum values as well. Second, I need not the single largest value of each cell, but its N largest values.

Is this possible with cells in Matlab?

**Update:** I have a pixel matrix that I get by running a filter on some input image file. From that matrix, I then split this matrix into tiles and want to keep only the N largest values per tile, while all other entries should be set to zero. (So I don't need the indices in the end, but they would allow me to create a new empty cell and copy over the large values.)

```
Tiles = mat2tiles(FilterResult, tileSize, tileSize);
```

If there is an easier way for my use case then using the [mat2tiles script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35085-split-nd-array-into-equal-sized-cells/content/mat2tiles.m), I'd be grateful to know.

Comment: Post a small example cell array and the exact output you want. Does each cell contain a numeric vector? A matrix? Do you want the index of the cell, or also the index of the entry within the cell?

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for pointing out the unclarity in my question. I made an update. Does this help to understand what I'm trying?

Comment: Yes, it's clearer now. Just one thing: for each matrix you want the highest values and their indices. Do you mean row and column indices, or linear indices? Also, do all matrices have the same size? In that case it would be better to use a 3D array than a cell array

Comment: The cells returned by `mat2tiles` are of equal size except the last cells which can be smaller when `tileSize` is no factor of the size of the input image. In the end, I don't need the indices, I just want to set all smaller values to zero. I though with having the indices of the largest elements, I could create an empty cell using `zeros` and copy those elements over. But there might be a better way, that I don't think of right now.

Comment: Got it. Does CitizenInsane's answer (or a minor adaptation of it) satisfy your needs?

Comment: I haven't managed to adapt it for my application right know, so I can't tell if it works for me right now. Do you think there is an easier way to set the smaller elements to zero than getting the indices and copying the large values over to a new cell?

Comment: From your update, you can put all operations in some `function [tile] = tileOperations(tile, N)` and the call `cellfun` only once with `tileOperations` function as parameter. Apparently `tileOperations` function can be as simple as `v = sort(tile(:)); threshold = v(end-N); tile(title < threshold) = 0`

Comment: @CitizenInsane Geart, I'll try that and hope there are won't be repeated values in the cells. ;) If you'd even have a fix for that, it would be great!

Comment: For instance [`unique`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) *(which also sorts elements)* ... or some more complex operations for each tile you can all put into `tileOperations` ... ;)

Comment: @CitizenInsane Thanks, that worked. Since this is what I ended up using, would you mind putting that into a small answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome. I have updated my answer. BR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routine [`cellfun`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) can return the multiple arguments of the function you're passing in (see the documentation). So, assuming each cell contains a numeric vector of values, you can obtain the `N` largest elements of each cell like this:

```
% Using random data for the_cell    
the_cell{1, 1} = rand(1, 12);
the_cell{1, 2} = rand(1, 42);
the_cell{2, 1} = rand(1, 18);
the_cell{2, 2} = rand(1, 67);

% First sort elements in each cell in descending order and keep indices
[s, i] = cellfun(@(x)sort(x(:), 'descend'), the_cell, 'UniformOutput', false);

% Then, in each resulting `s` and `i` cell arrays, 
% take only the `N` first elements and indices
N = 4;
NLargestValues = cellfun(@(x)x(1:N), s, 'UniformOutput', false);
NLargestIndices = cellfun(@(x)x(1:N), i, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

NB: `UniformOutput` is set to false because outputs are not scalar.

**Update**

From your updates and comments we had, you can put all operations in some `tileOperations` function:

```
% Operation to perform for each tile in the_cell array
function [tile] = tileOperations(tile, N) 
%[
    % Return unique sorted values of the tile
    v = unique(tile(:));

    % Find threshold index
    i = length(v) - N;
    if (i <= 1), return; end % Quick exit if not enough elements 

    % Set elements below threshold to zero
    threshold = v(i);
    tile(tile < threshold) = 0.0;    
%]
end
```

You can then call `cellfun` only once to repetitively apply operations on all tiles in `the_cell`:

```
filteredTiles = cellfun(@(x)tileOperations(x), the_cell, 'UniformOutput', false);
```